# Double degree: why was this question closed as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question, duplicates

I think that the closure of the question

[Double PhD: is it really worth it?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/79875/20058)

as duplicate of

[Is doing two PhD's a good path?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/17232/20058)

is based on a wrong assumption.

A double PhD degree is a *single* PhD jointly awarded by two universities on a *single topic*, and has nothing to do with two degrees on two different topics.

Thus, I disagree with the close reason and I voted to reopen it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This maybe a case of differences across academia resulting in an unclear question. I have never heard of two universities awarding a single degree and would not term such an activity as a "double PhD". I did my PhD in a *strange* department in the US that was split across two universities (so very similar to what you are describing). At the point of defending our theses we had to choose which university our degree would be from and we had to format our theses according to the policies of that University. There was no option, nor any discussion amongst faculty or students, to get a jointly awarded degree.

If this jointly awarded double PhD is in fact different from getting two PhDs, I think a clearer description would be very helpful for US and UK academics.

Comment: I thought that what a double degree is could have been inferred from my answer to the linked question, and from the other answers too. If it's not clear enough, tomorrow I can expand somewhat the description.

Comment: Out of curiosity: are you aware of the existence, especially within the EU, of double degrees in this sense at the Master's level?

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano nope. I never heard of anything like this in the US or UK. I need to look it up.

Comment: It's quite common in Europe. We have agreements with several universities, perhaps also with one in UK. That's why some students wish to have this possibility also at the PhD level.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano this is a clear misunderstanding. I reopened the question, but if you get a chance please edit something into the question to clarify it.

Comment: Thanks. I'll surely do it tomorrow... now time to sleep ;-)

Comment: I've edited my answer. Let me know if now there is enough context.